# Join two rows that contain a common column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure returning a table that looks like this:

```
ID | Job | Freight | Postage |  Job  | Type
-------------------------------------------
1  | 100 |      0  |      0  |  5.00 |  J
2  | 101 |      0  |      0  |  8.00 |  J
3  | 101 |   2.00  |      0  |     0 |  F
4  | 102 |      0  |      0  |  4.00 |  J
5  | 102 |      0  |   3.00  |     0 |  P
6  | 103 |      0  |      0  |  7.00 |  J
7  | 104 |      0  |      0  |  9.00 |  J
8  | 105 |      0  |      0  |  6.00 |  J
```

I would like it to return the table like this:

```
ID | Job | Freight | Postage |  Job  | Type
-------------------------------------------
1  | 100 |      0  |      0  |  5.00 |  J
2  | 101 |   2.00  |      0  |  8.00 |  J
4  | 102 |      0  |   3.00  |  4.00 |  J
6  | 103 |      0  |      0  |  7.00 |  J
7  | 104 |      0  |      0  |  9.00 |  J
8  | 105 |      0  |      0  |  6.00 |  J
```

The intended result would join rows that have matching **Job** numbers and change the **Freight** and **Postage** values of each so that they appear on one line. There will never be an instance of a **Job** having both a **Freight** and **Postage** value, it will be one or the other or none at all.

From what I have seen it looks like I may need to use the PIVOT operator to achieve this but that seems overly complex. Is there a way that I could achieve this result using a CASE or IF expression?

I am already using a SUM function to obtain my values for **Freight** and **Postage**. I am unsure how I would make those values show up on the **Type** J row.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction.Type = 'F' THEN Transaction.Price END) OVER (PARTITION BY TransactionLine.ID) AS Freight
```

Comment: From what you've posted, why not just `SUM` things?

Comment: SUM or MAX would work.   There have been many other questions like this before.   I'll see if I can find a good duplicate

Comment: Can you should the code that you have tried?

Comment: Although the flagged duplicate is concerned with replacing NULLs, the same exact answer serves to replace zeroes, and works for merging more than two rows.   You would have to simply hard-code the 'J' for `Type` since it seems every `Job` has a "J" value, and that's the value you want.